# How to export Pandas dataframe to Sql file

Tags: python, pandas

I made a code where I have a Pandas dataframe. With this code I export my dataframe to Excel and I insert it in my local database.

I'd like also to export it directly in a Sql file.

I will show you my code and what I tried.

This is my code:

```
df3 = df3[["home","away","scorehome","scoreaway","htresult","shresult","result","best_bets","oddtwo","oddthree","over05ht","over15ht","over05sh","over15sh","over05","over15","over25","over35","over45","goal","esito","tournament","uniquefield"]]
df3 = df3.sort_values('best_bets')



# determining the name of the file
file_name = camp + '' + '.xlsx'
 
# saving the excel
df3.to_excel(file_name)
print('Tournament is written to Excel File successfully.')



mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="mydb"
)

# Create a SQLAlchemy engine to connect to the MySQL database
engine = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/xxx?')


# Convert the Pandas DataFrame to a format for MySQL table insertion
df3.to_sql('fullresults', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

With this code, at the end, I insert my dataframe on my local DB

I tried to replace this:
`engine = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/mydb?')`

with this:
`engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///mydb.sql")`

but I get a file that I can't open and read

Thanks for your help

Comment: What kind of output file does this produce? Maybe try to specify dtypes in to_sql

Comment: @PaoloJ42 How can I do it? I get a fine unreadable